# Symfony 3.4 Estás a punto de enviar una información no segura

Tags: symfony, seguridad, https, fos-user-bundle

recurro a ustedes en busca de ayuda, ya que me aparece una advertencia de **sitio no seguro** en mi proyecto php que usa symfony 3.4 con el bundle fosuser.

La advertencia me aparece solo con google chrome, y solo al realizar el login, aqui el mensaje:

**Estás a punto de enviar una información no segura**

**Dado que la conexión que usa este sitio web no es completamente segura, otros usuarios podrán ver tu información.**

Al inspeccionando con DevTools veo que hay una llamada a login_check y en el area  response header aparece el atributo location con una url http:// pese a que mi sitio es https:// con certificado activo, sera que tiene que ver con alguna redirección interna del framework?

Aquí una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Talvez alguien sabe que debo hacer para que no aparezca la advertencia en google chrome?

Comment: Hola. Estás usando protocolo http. **(Eso se ve en tu Response headers)** Necesitas instalar un certificado y usar protocolo https. Mientras no lo hagas los navegadores van a seguir **chillando**. Si ya lo instalaste debes corregir el Location enviado en los encabezados. Observa que dice: **Location: http://**

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con la ultima actualización de Chrome, en otro navegador funciona sin problemas, ya lo probé me paso lo mismo, solo que ahora estoy buscando algun comunicado oficial de chrome donde indique esta alerta de seguridad.

Comment: Gracias, ahora  funciona sin problemas